# SQL Server : filter on dates from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm pretty new to SQL Server so this may be a pretty easy question

I have a log table view that looks like the following:

[image]

And a table that logs the start and stop of a run that looks like the following:

[image]

I would like to filter data from the first table between the start and stop times in the second table. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried to solve this problem yourself?  If so, please include the SQL in the question.

Comment: Table names are always useful when discussing SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular `join` to match a date-range:

```
select  *
from    Entries e
join    Runs r
on      r.StartTime <= e.EntryTime
        and (
          e.EntryTime <= r.StopTime
          or r.StopTime is null -- For a run that has not yet stopped
        )
```

But your example data suggests there is a foreign key, which would eliminate the need for date-range matching:

```
select  *
from    Entries e
join    Runs r
on      e.ProjectRunId = r.ProjectRunId
```